# Sharing "protected" files between web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I have a single c# MVC web application consisting of a "backend" part and a "frontend" part.

Through the backend a logged in user can upload images, which are saved in a subfolder of "App_Data".

Some parts of the frontend is public and can display images from the "App_Data" folder via a ashx handler.
Other parts of the frontend require users to login before being able to see images.
Furthermore the frontend allows authenticated users to download multiple images via dynamically created zip-files.

So, both the download feature and the ashx evaluates user credentials.

Now I wish to split this application into two separate ones.
One backend application for administrating the images and other data.
And one frontend application for viewing and downloading.

My question is this:
Taking into account that

- database storage is not an option because of the amount of data
- the apps will be hosted on a co-hosting environment
- that I cannot create virtual directories or similar for mapping directories between the applications
- and that the frontend application must pass along and/or evaluate custom credentials before allowing viewing and downloading of files....

...what's the best and cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: What about using cloud storage?  You can use google drive, skydrive, or blob storage in azure.

Comment: I don't feel that's an option. I want to keep everything inside the application structure. Someone answered a somewhat similar question here on SO suggesting the use of HttpHandlers between applications. Not sure how I'd implement authentication in such a setup, though.

Comment: Is database not an option because you have a cap on database size? If not, why rule it out? If you MUST split this into two, then it seems you'll need some type of SSO and a mechanism in which you can delegate the image request "on behalf" of the actual user. What type of Authentication are you using?

Comment: I'm ruling database out because of a cap and because of the potential total size of storage required when all users get going. I'm using a custom authentication model based on session (please don't give a "the web is stateless" lecture). Thinking of switching to the built in Form auth, though.